# split function to highlight search term in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, split, array.prototype.map

I have some data that Im mapping through and trying to highlight the search term entered into a field. I have this little section where I pass the string value (which I verified console logs correctly) into my splitResult function. It is supposed to split that string into pieces, index them, and return the string with highlighted parts... how do I return the pieces?? Example: (the item.title should show and is not) If there is not enough code to understand this sandbox might help..
[search app](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-bar-react-s13cm)

```
//split the search term
  const splitResult = (result) => {
    result.split(new RegExp(`(${searchTerm})`, `gi`)).map((piece, index) => {
      return <span
          key={index}
          style={{
            background: piece.toLowerCase() === searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase() ?    
            "YELLOW" : "TRANSPARENT",
          }}
        >
          {piece} //<--is this right?//
        </span>
    });
};
```

```
//some of the rendering
<div key={item.index}>
     <div>{splitResult(item.title)}</div>
     {item.content.map((i, index) => {
     return <div key={index}>{i.text}</div>;
     })}
     <div className={styles.searchLink}
           onClick={() => {
           context.setCurrentSlide(item.index);}} 
          >Go To This Slide {item.index}
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: the `splitResult` function is not returning anything

Comment: isn't it returning a span with the "pieces" of the string passed in it? Or do you mean i have not shown the data file? (result is a string that equals "Lesson Checkpoint".) I just didn't show it,

Comment: you have a return statement inside the map but the mapped array is not returned. You have to add `return` before `result.split`

Comment: your a god thank you i couldnt see it